# SQL Server 2008 : Counting the number of records stored in a category

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL Server and I got a question that puzzles me.

I have 2 data tables `Category` and `Product`. Below are the tables in details.

**Category**:

```
------------------------------------------------------
 categoryId | categoryName      | desc
------------------------------------------------------
 1          | Shirt             | Men's Shirt
 2          | Jeans             | Men's Pants
 3          | Accessories       | Women's Accessories
------------------------------------------------------
```

**Product**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
productID   | desc                     | categoryId
---------------------------------------------------------------
 1          | Slim-fit Classic Shirt   | 1
 2          | Denim Slim-fit jeans     | 2
 3          | Denim Regular-fit jeans  | 2
 4          | Bracelet                 | 3
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I get the exact output as follows?

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 categoryId | categoryName      | numOfRecord | desc
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 1          | Shirt             | 1           | Men's Shirt
 2          | Jeans             | 2           | Men's Pants
 3          | Accessories       | 1           | Women's Accessories
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [COUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) and [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx).

Try this:

```
SELECT c.categoryId, c.categoryName, count(*) as numOfRecord, p.[desc]
FROM dbo.Category AS c INNER JOIN dbo.Product AS p
ON c.categoryId = p.categoryId
GROUP BY c.categoryId, c.categoryName, p.[desc];
```